# Can React-Redux and React Context API be used both in the same project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-context

I'm an angular developer for many years and I tried to switch some of my new projects by using React & React Native, but I had an hard time deciding which state management could suit better for a project that could grow bigger, and my question was if I could use both solutions by having Redux as a central storage and the Context API for a better management to pass props to nested components, is it a good pattern to use both or should I stick to one of them.

Comment: It really depends.  Sometimes you want to keep some state local to some feature but don't want it leaking into your overall store so it might make sense to use Contexts.  Other parts might be cross-cutting and it may make sense for Redux.  It's all up to your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the use case.

If you're looking for top-down props pass down structure where the same data is used over multiple depths of components (such as Theme, Auth, etc.), Context API is the way.

If you're looking for a big store where you can dynamically manage data and constantly update it, Redux is the way.

If you need both, my opinion is that it's perfectly okay to do so.

They're not very heavy, (I guess a Redux.. a lil bit?) and they do have different purposes anyway.

Comment: Although they do have different use cases, I wouldn't say they have different purposes. Context can absolutely fill the same role as Redux in most cases

Comment: True, Context API can fill the same role, but considering that Redux is optimized for constant state update, the performance would hugely outscale Context. Updating Context as frequently would result in a lot of unnecessary re-renders, unless the components are memoized. Not to mention that memoization of components itself is a overhead

Comment: Updating a key in a redux store causes a rerender as well, doesn't it? Just like updating the state in a Context. Asking a real question here, not arguing :P

Comment: @ThalesKenne you're probably right. Though, the ```connect``` function runs a shallow compare on the previous & updated state. In that sense, using ContextAPI&memoized components and Redux are similar, I guess. For specific details we would have to look more into the implementation details of each library, but assuming that they hold a similar logic it would just come down to how easy it is to implement them, I guess?